# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LoDashStatic' in second params of Lodash/fp orderBy

Tags: typescript, lodash

I got this weird problem in my React project using typescript and lodash/fp orderBy function. The orderBy function description is `_.orderBy(iteratees, orders, collection)`. The second parameter which is orders, this can either be a string or string[], has a warning in my variable declared (I have also added an image for clearer description):

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LoDashStatic'.ts(2769)
fp.d.ts(2298, 9): The last overload is declared here.
```

But whenever I used a direct value or static one, the error is gone. I'll also attached a code snippet here:

```
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState('');
  const [sortOrder, setSortOrder] = useState<string>('asc');

  const onSort = (column: string) => {
    if (sortBy === column) {
      setSortOrder(sortOrder === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc');
    } else {
      setSortBy(column);
      setSortOrder('asc');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isEmpty(sortBy) && !isEmpty(sortOrder)) {
      const sortedList = orderBy(sortBy, sortOrder, usersList);
      setUsersList(sortedList);
    }
  }, [sortBy, sortOrder]);
```

The `sortOrder` state is the one who has the error.

Thank you for help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY0KZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fix it:

```
const [sortOrder, setSortOrder] = useState<'asc' | 'desc'>('asc');
```